# Static QApplication variable made Mac reports an crash on exit

Tags: c++, macos, qt, static-variables

the following code run well on Windows or Linux (Debian) but on Mac report a crash on exit:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  static QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPushButton w; w.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

I need this app variable must be static.
I work around this by:

```
static QApplication& app = *new QApplication(argc, argv);
```

But I don't like this style. Do you have any suggestion? 
Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**: adding image about the report (and update the code sample that I'm using):
[image]

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: Why do you need it static? You can always use ```QApplication::instance()``` to retrieve the current instance. You could just have a static pointer to the return of the instance call.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, your are answer. I needed because I want to retrieve it  somewhere without passing as an argument. Thank again.

Comment: @hank: it's a long message about crash, I will update the question with the image later.

Comment: Why didn't you mention that the crash happens on exit? That's the detail that makes all the difference, and it should have gotten you thinking!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assertion that it "works" is metaphorical at best. You failed to mention that the crash happens on exit. That's a very important detail.

The reason for the crash is that you lose control of the order of destruction. Values of static storage duration, such as `QApplication` in your example, are destructed by the C++ runtime sometime after `main()` exits.

Qt uses static variables internally for various purposes. It so happens that when the `QApplication::~QApplication` destructor runs, the values of these variables have already been destructed. The crash happens in `qt_call_post_routines()`, in the `cleanupDevicesList()` post routine. It tries to access dead objects.

The reason that it "works" on Windows and Linux is the same reason that it "doesn't work" on Mac: you're facing undefined behavior. Undefined behavior simply means that it's neither guaranteed to work, nor to fail. You happen to see both behavior extremes by chance. The crux of the matter is that you should not write code that invokes undefined behavior. It "works" on Windows today, for you, but might not work during an important customer demonstration.

Comment: I agree with your explaination. I like to use static somewhere but I would be more careful than. Thanks!

Comment: @aviit Use static only when the object has no dependencies on other static objects.

Comment: @KubaOber good advice. Unfortunately, with libraries, it's hard to know whether objects of a given class's type will have dependencies on other static objects. For future readers: `QApplication` does have these dependencies, at least in Qt 5.10.

Answer (score 1):

Do not define `QApplication app` as `static`.

You can use [`qApp`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#qApp) or [`QCoreApplication::instance()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#instance) in any place of your code.

Example:

```
QString appDir = qApp->applicationDirPath();
```

is the same as

```
QString appDir = QCoreApplication::instance()->applicationDirPath();
```

Comment: yes, I often use qApp, I've just forgotten. Thanks. I just want to ask/discuss why define as static make Mac report an crash.